# PL/SQL garbage value cleaning

Tags: sql, plsql, scripting, oracle-sqldeveloper

A table contains millions of records in which there are 12 critical columns that contain some garbage values.
Not all records in these 12 columns are garbage. There are some records which are fine while others are garbage.

So i want to write a PL/SQL script to clean these garbage values without using the update statement 12 times.
I have a code written but it doesn't seem to work for my cause. 
Any suggestions to modify the code or to change the code entirely are welcome. I suppose dynamic 
SQL would be used here but I don't have any knowledge of it what so ever and I'm really short on time.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
count_total number := 0;
i           number :=0;
ch          varchar2(10);
ch2         varchar2(10);

CURSOR cursor_sim_b IS 
select a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, -- To identify
trim(translate(a1,'0123456789',' ')) a_1,             -- garbage values
trim(translate(a2,'0123456789',' ')) a_2,
trim(translate(a3,'0123456789',' ')) a_3,
trim(translate(a4,'0123456789',' ')) a_4,
trim(translate(a5,'0123456789',' ')) a_5,
trim(translate(a6,'0123456789',' ')) a_6,
trim(translate(b1,'0123456789',' ')) b_1,
trim(translate(b2,'0123456789',' ')) b_2,
trim(translate(b3,'0123456789',' ')) b_3,
trim(translate(b4,'0123456789',' ')) b_4,
trim(translate(b5,'0123456789',' ')) b_5,
trim(translate(b6,'0123456789',' ')) b_6
from  temp_clean;

sim_b_rec cursor_sim_b%rowtype;

BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('OUTSIDE the CURSOR ');

FOR sim_b_rec IN cursor_sim_b
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line('OUTSIDE the FOR  LOOP ');

FOR i IN 1..6
LOOP
ch := 'a_' ||i;
dbms_output.put_line('Inside the LOOP '||ch);


if sim_b_rec.ch is not null   -- error in passing 'ch' to cursor
then                          -- error says 'ch' not declared
BEGIN

execute immediate 'update temp_clean
set sim_b_rec.ch = NULL';

EXCEPTION
     WHEN  OTHERS THEN
     ROLLBACK;
END;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('a'||i||'<' || sim_b_rec.ch || '>');
end if;

ch2 := 'b_' ||i;
if sim_b_rec.ch2 is not null
then
BEGIN
execute immediate 'update temp_clean
set sim_b_rec.ch2 = NULL';

EXCEPTION
     WHEN  OTHERS THEN
     ROLLBACK;
END;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('b'||i||'<'|| sim_b_rec.ch2 || '>');
end if;

END LOOP;
END LOOP;



COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: 12 `UPDATE`s is surely better than 1 UPDATE millions of times?  Don't use a cursor on millions of rows...

Comment: its a while since i did some oracle but i believe you don't need to execute  `execute immediate 'update temp_sim_clean
set sim_b_rec.ch2 = NULL';` a few million times, on time should do it ;)

Comment: @MatBailie What would you suggest I use? I'm not very familiar with the concepts of PL/SQL. But have to submit this very soon.

Comment: @Aツ How? Sorry I'm a little clueless here :(

Comment: For each column please tell us 1) how a garbage value is identified 2) what should be done for the garbage value ? Very likely PL/SQL is a wrong tool when old-boring SQL does the job perfectly well.

Comment: @Abhinav your update statements have no where clause, they'll update all rows anyway.

Comment: @user272735 the translate function checks if column has anything from 1-9, wherever 1-9 is encountered, it replaces it with a blank space. So if the value is not garbage (actually the correct data type for the columns is number) it will make the column null. 
The trim function will then trim the blank spaces created by the translate function. That's how garbage values will be identified.

2) The garbage value is to be replaced with null. So the if statement checks if a record is not null (i.e garbage because the correct value is made null by trim & translate.

Comment: @user272735 I know it can be done by normal SQL very easily but I have to write a PL/SQL script. It's a task.

Comment: Your way of identifying garbage does not seem right. You are translating every value to `NULL`.Provide us sample valid values and garbage values to help you further.

Comment: By "it's a task", are you saying that it is a homework assignment?  Exactly what does the homework assignment require?  Unless you are required to use dynamic SQL, I'd write a PL/SQL function that cleans one value (correctly) and simply call that function in a single `UPDATE` statement.  But perhaps that isn't what your professor is trying to teach you.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not an Answer. Perhaps a question to OP.

I guess Your way of finding garbage does not work. You are translating every value to `NULL`. Assuming the Garbage contains Non-Numeric.

See below:

```
select translate('567','0123456789',NULL),
length(translate('567','0123456789',NULL) )
 from dual;
 -- OUTPUT: NULL NULL

select translate('abc56','0123456789',NULL) ,
length(translate('abc56','0123456789',NULL) )
from dual;
 -- OUTPUT: NULL NULL

select translate('%&12ab','0123456789',NULL),
length(translate('%&12ab','0123456789',NULL) )
 from dual;
   -- OUTPUT: NULL NULL
```

Just to make sure everything that is Translated is `NULL` have added `LENGTH` check.

Provide us sample valid values and garbage values to help you further